# How can I query the mysql database for a variable, if exists create another variable, if not insert?

Tags: php, mysql

say I have a variable

$id = mt_rand();

how can I query the mysql database to see if the variable exists in the row id, if it does exist then change the variable $id, once the variable is unique to all other stored ids, then insert it into the database?

Thanks you guys.

Comment: explain "once the variable is unique to all other stored ids"

Comment: say I have a number 10994566, I need to check it with other numbers in that particular row, if it unique then insert it, if not generate another number.

Comment: probably means "if variable is not in database"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$con = mysql_connect("<host>","<login>","<pass>");
if ($con) {
    mysql_select_db('<schemata>', $con);
    $found = false;
    while (!$found) {
        $idIamSearching = mt_rand();
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM <table> WHERE <idColumnName>='".$idIamSearching."'");
        $result = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        if ($result[0] > 0) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO <table> (<column>) VALUES ('".$idIamSearching."')");
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

Your description is hard to understand, so, this is something that could give you pointers...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Basically what I am doing is I am creating a little online game from scratch as a project. When a user signs up to the site to play I will generate a random ID for their character. Now seeing as mt_rand isn't random, I need to check if the number that is generated isn't already someone's id. If it is already someones id, generate another id until it is unique to there account. If that makes sense :)

Comment: And auto increment is not an option, I know the benefits of it, but this problem got me stumped :/

Comment: Can I ask what this bit of code is? if ($result[0] > 0) { what does the [0] do? Thanks for your help much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any loop in this code... It might check if $id exists in database and if does, generate new variable, if doesn't... INSERT. So if your $id exists, you have to generate new $id and query table again.

Comment: @Beginner PHPer $result is fetched as array, [0] is array item number 0 - first array item, that is count(*) from that query.

Comment: Sorry @Deele, **I really did not see** that. I was wondering why this answer was accepted, haha, my bad...  +1 for answer

Comment: I can't plus one yet, I only joined today, but this site is awesome, it is better than any book anyone could buy!

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT COUNT(*) as count from table where row_id="'.$variable.'" LIMIT 1'
```

make sure to escape the variable if it's user input or if it's going to have more than alphanumeric characters

then fetch the row and check if count is 1 or greater than 0

if one, then it exists and try again (in a loop)

although, auto increment on the id field would allow you to avoid this step

Answer (score 0):

```
$bExists = 0;
while(!$bExists){
    // Randomly generate id variable
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id");
    if($result){
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $bExists = 1;
    } else {
        // Insert into database
        $bExists = 1;
    }
}
```

1 Randomly generate id variable
2 Query database for it
2.1 Result? exit
2.2 No result? Insert